Setting cookie config using vue-cookie-next library in Vue 3 project
I'm using the vue-cookie-next library to set the cookies inside my Vue 3 project. The problem is that when I try to set a cookie with a config object the cookie is not created in the browser.
That's the function (I'm using Vue 3 Navigations guards also) I use.
function createCookies() {
  const $cookie = VueCookieNext;
  const access_token = "access_token_test";
  const expiry_token = "expiry_token_test";
  const refresh_token = "refresh_token_test";
  const config = {
    path: "/",
    expire: 60 * 10,
    domain: process.env.VUE_APP_NUXT_HOST,
    secure: process.env.VUE_APP_NUXT_ENV === "production",
  };
  // Set cookies
  $cookie.setCookie(
    `project.access_token`,
    access_token
  );
  $cookie.setCookie(
    `project.expiry_token`,
    expiry_token,
    config
  );
  $cookie.setCookie(
    `project.refresh_token`,
    refresh_token
  );
}

The access_token and refresh_token cookie are created in the browser but the expiry_token is not created in the browser
